# c# - Listbox won't refresh when i remove an item (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, process, listbox, taskmanager

I'm making a simple task manager. So far I've been able to get all the processes stored into a `Process` array and then add it into a listBox. Now when i press the **kill** button, the process gets killed but it still shows in the listBox. Also when i open a process when my code is running, it doesn't show up, i have to re-run my code. Here's what i have...

```
private void getProcs()
{
    procArray = Process.GetProcesses();
    processListBox.Items.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i<procArray.Length; i++)
    {
        processListBox.Items.Add(procArray[i].ProcessName);
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getProcs();
}

private void killButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    procArray[processListBox.SelectedIndex].Kill();
    getProcs();
}
```

i even try calling the `getProcs()` function again in the `killButton_Click` function to get a new list. It seems to "refresh" the listBox (as in i dont see my selected index in the listbox anymore, but when i search for the process i just killed it's still in the listBox (i know that the process was killed because the application closed.)

I've also tried using the **timer component**, but that was super stupid because there are background processes that pop on and off all the time, so it was pretty much impossible to select anything.

**EDIT:**
ok so i figured out a way to make the listBox 'refresh' whenever i kill a process, i just added `.WaitForExit()` right after i kill the process.Turns out that the .Kill() function is asynchronous, so that's why you gotta wait for it to exit.

Now... i dont know how to get it to 'refresh' whenever a process is opened. Currently i have a cheap way of doing it. I made a "refresh" button to manually update the listbox...

Comment: The window closing doesnt mean the process ended.  Some do housekeeping for a time afterwards - Chrome is an example

Comment: Might be better to wire up the `Exited` event, when the process gets killed, refresh the list box within that event handler. Be sure to enable `EnableRaisingEvents` prior to wiring up the said event.

Comment: @Plutonix it does end the process, it also closes it on the Window's task manager